# Option to put text such as field being edited on Android soft keyboard (full screen/extract mode)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Is there any way that I can put text such as the name of the EditText field currently being edited on the full screen Android soft keyboard which stays even after the user has typed in text in that field?  I noticed that in EditorInfo there is a label attribute

> public CharSequence label - A label to show to the user describing the text they are writing.

but I can't seem to find any way to set its value from an EditText field.  Does anyone know how to?  I also know that it is possible to use a hint, but it is not an option as I said before, I don't want the text describing the field currently being edited to disappear once they start typing.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hmm, this is already the default behavior... To be clear: You have set a regular hint in your EditText, you click the EditText in landscape orientation which opens the softKeyboard in "full-screen mode", and your hint or existing text is not displayed?

Comment: Well I want to put a description of the field which stays there whether or not the user has already typed in text.  With a hint, once a user types in a text it is no longer displayed, but I want it to be displayed whether or not there is text already.  I will also update the original question to make that more clear.